# How to measure information content or quantify information in a query vector?

Tags: information-theory

I have a query that consists of a number of attributes. I would like to measure the amount of information in that query. Then measure how that information content is reduced or not affected if I remove a certain attribute.

Is there a measure or metric from information theory that solves this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Is the query random? Do you get a set of values as a result of the query? You need to elaborate on what your random variables are...

Comment: The query is submitted by a user against a data repository (database, xml file, etc.). Think of the query as being the random variable Q which consist of several items. I thought that I could probably represent the items as binary values. E.g. if lets say I have 100 attributes/items in general then a query should contain at least one of those items. If a query contains the item i1 then the value of that item will be 1 otherwise it is 0. Q={1,1,1,0,0,1,0…..}

Comment: you mean the result of a query is a {0,1} indicator vector? If the results of one query is random, you can measure the entropy of that conditional distribution, perhaps? BTW, you can edit the question to put those details. I'm sure it will help others too.